# switch statement, and other erros

Tags: c++, string, switch-statement

I'm trying to brush up on some simple C++ programs, and this one has some errors and I'm not understanding why.  I'll write the errors in the comments above the line

```
int main(void)
{

bool x = true;
char userInput;
double weight;
string planetName;

while (x == true)
{
                                      //endl; has the error "expected a ;"
    cout << "Please enter your weight:" endl;
    cin >> weight;

    cout << "Please enter a planet name (The moon and pluto count)" endl;
    cin >> planetName;

    for (int i = 0; i < planetName[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        planetName[i] = tolower(planetName[i]);
    }

           //planetName has the error "expression must have integral or enum types"
    switch (planetName)
    {
         //mercury has the error "too many characters in character constant"
    case 'mercury' :
        cout << "Your weight is :" << weight * .4155;
    case 'venus' :
        cout << "Your weight is :" << weight * .8975;
    case 'earth' :
        cout << "Your weight is :" << weight * 1;
    case 'mars' :
        cout << "Your weight is :" << weight * .3507;
    case 'jupiter' :
        cout << "Your weight is :" << weight * 2.5374;
    case 'saturn' :
        cout << "Your weight is :" << weight * 1.0677;
    case 'uranus' :
        cout << "Your weight is :" << weight * .8947;
    case 'neptune' :
        cout << "Your weight is :" << weight * 1.1794;
    case 'pluto' :
        cout << "Your weight is :" << weight * .0899;
    case 'moon' :
        cout << "Your weight is :" << weight * .116;
    }





    cout << "Try again?" << endl;
    cout << "Press Y to see your weight on a different planet,or N to exit." << endl;
    cin >> userInput;
                                   // both == signs have "operand types are incompatable"
    if (userInput == "y" || userInput == "Y")
    {
        break;
    }
    else if (userInput == "n" || userInput == "N")
    {
        x = false;
    }

}




PressEnterToContinue();

return 0;
}
```

If I'm doing something in a less than intelligent way, or you think of a more intelligent way to do any of this, please feel free to say so.  I don't really like using while loops, but sometimes I just can't think of anything else quickly for short programs like this.

Comment: Why is this tagged `C`?

Comment: change ' to ". ' can only contain ONE char.

Comment: If you'd like to do this in a more modern C++ way, you might use a `std::map< std::string, double >` to map planet names to gravitational ratios.

Comment: It's tagged as C, because I wasn't positive that most of this wasn't correct C syntax, and thanks for the map advice, I'll look into it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                                  //endl; has the error "expected a ;"
cout << "Please enter your weight:" endl;
```

As it says, you put an `endl` where it expected a `;`. The problem is the missing `<<`.

```
       //planetName has the error "expression must have integral or enum types"
switch (planetName)
```

As it says, a `switch` must have an integral or enum type. Use `if` instead.

```
     //mercury has the error "too many characters in character constant"
case 'mercury' :
```

As it says, a character constant must be a character. Use `"` for string constants.

```
                               // both == signs have "operand types are incompatable"
if (userInput == "y" || userInput == "Y")
```

Since `userInput` is a char, it cannot be equivalent to a string.

Comment: Very comprehensive, although you forgot to mention the missing `break` statements.

Comment: I don't think he mentioned the break statements since I can't use a switch statement (the way I'm doing it) anyway.  Thanks for the comments and answers!

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++ switch statements are defined only for integer types, such as int or shot or long or enum or char or their unsigned versions.

Also strings should be enclosed in double quotes.